# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT when getting Reusable cell for TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**Background**

Im trying to reuse a cell called 'PhotoCell' used for a different feed in this feed.  After placing some break points my code gets to this point of grabbing the ReusableCell from PhotoCell and errors out like this:

```
2019-10-24 10:17:45.962720-0700 Gallery[15203:376468] 
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:usingPresentationValues:], 
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore_Sim/UIKit-3899.13.13/UITableView.m:8589 
2019-10-24 10:17:45.978775-0700 Gallery[15203:376468] ***

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier EventFeedPhotoCell - 
must register a nib or a class for the identifier 
or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

So I know where the error is occurring but I'm not clear how to debug this via print statements or the like.  How can I troubleshoot this?

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //Get a event feed photo cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.eventFeedPhotoTableCell, for: indexPath) as! PhotoCell

    //Get the photo for this row
    let photo = photos[indexPath.row]

    //Set the details for the cell
    cell.setPhoto(photo)

    return cell

}
```

Comment: what is reuse identifier

Comment: Before sequence, add.  print(tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.eventFeedPhotoTableCell, for: indexPath).  to check the type. And )before accessing photos, I would add 
print("photos nb=", photos.count, "index", indexPath.row)

Comment: @Jok3r ReuseIdentifier is 'EventFeedPhotoCell'

Comment: can you share your tableview related methods ?

Comment: have you set up the reuse identifier in the Xcode IDE Cell Class ?

Comment: I think my issue is i reused another tableview cell class 'PhotoCell' that has outlets to another VC.  Let me create a new tableview cell class specifically for this reusable cell and see if that works

Comment: ya.. the problem is with your cell identifier. please be careful when you work with cell. and also please set up the tableview delegate and datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree that the cell identifier seems to be the problem.  A pattern that I've recently adopted (replacing enums and constants) is to use a static property on the custom cell for the ID as this reliable and makes it very obvious what's happening and what cell is being used where:

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
  static let cellID = "WhateverStringYouLike" //as it'll never be visible

  //all the usual stuff
}
```

and then use it like like:

```
//in viewDidLoad()
tableView.register(MyCustomCell.self, for: MyCustomCell.cellID)


//in cellForRowAt
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyCustomCell.cellID, for: indexPath)
```

Comment: Why static? The usual thing is an ordinary instance property. — But the reuse identifier in the storyboard does not benefit from this in any case.

Comment: Accepted the answer.  Will go back and figure out why doing this as I did in my Constants file didn't work.  What does 'registering' my cell do, I've never done that before?

Comment: It's the more recent API for preparing a cell for reuse.  It has the advantages that it links to the type, so you no longer need to cast the cell when dequeueing it, if there are no available cells for reuse the tableView creates the cell for you (so you don't have to), and because of all that the returned cell isn't an optional.  Basically it cuts out a load of boilerplate code and makes the code cleaner/safer as it removes the optional component.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are trying to dequeue the cell with `EventFeedPhotoCell` but you might have given the cell reuse identifier name as something else, please cross check the cell identifier name.

Comment: also check for upper / lowercase typo.